# Using python to remove all strings and comments from python code

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to count the uniqueness of my variable names in all the python code I've written. To do so, I need to strip out all the keywords and reserved words (which are known), the comments and the strings. For example, the following code:

```
''' long comment '''
for x in range(y, y+foo):
    print "Hello", 'world', '''lookout for the # tricky nest''', q # comment
```

should be stripped to the tokens of `for, x, in, range, y, foo, print, q` which can be further parsed using a known set of keywords. Is this possible using the python engine itself (maybe with the [ast module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html))?

Comment: @AvinashRaj right now I have an over-complicated pyparsing code to try to interpret python code. I realized that this could be done in-house with the engine itself. Since I don't know the AST module and the pyarsing is irrelevant to the question here I left it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my first time playing with the `ast` module, but it was relatively easy to collect all the object names referenced in a source:

```
import ast

class Visit(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        ast.NodeVisitor.__init__(self)
        self.s = set()
    def visit_Name(self,node):
        self.s.add(node.id)

with open('x.py') as f:
    a=ast.parse(f.read())
v = Visit()
v.visit(a)
print v.s
```

Where `x.py` was:

```
''' long comment '''
q=7
y=0
foo=10
for x in range(y,y+foo):
    print "Hello", 'world', '''lookout for the # tricky nest''', q # comment
```

Output:

```
set(['q', 'y', 'range', 'foo', 'x'])
```

Note that keywords aren't included already, but it does pick up the function name `range`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're more concerned with getting the list of variables rather than how to strip out all strings, comments, etc., you could try something like:

```
for name in (set(locals()) | set(globals())):
    print(name)
```

to print anything that shows up in either the local dictionary or global dictionary. Use `dir(myobject)` to get the variables for `myobject`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html